# ITK Fast Marching output

Tags: c++, image-processing, itk

I'm using ITK to do some preprocessing and I wanted to test something with the Fast Marching filter and the Geodesic Active Contour filter.
I'm following the algorithm described in the [ITK software guide](http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf), section 9.3.3.
However, I'm not getting the expected results. I'm working with a 3D image.

Here is my code:

```cpp
AnisotropicDiffusionFilter::Pointer anisotropic_filter = AnisotropicDiffusionFilter::New();
anisotropic_filter->SetInput(itk_image_in);
anisotropic_filter->SetTimeStep(0.0625);
anisotropic_filter->SetNumberOfIterations(5);
anisotropic_filter->SetConductanceParameter(3.0); 
anisotropic_filter->Update();
 
GradientFilter::Pointer gradient_filter = GradientFilter::New();
gradient_filter->SetInput(anisotropic_filter->GetOutput());
gradient_filter->SetSigma(0.5);
gradient_filter->Update();
 
SigmoidFilter::Pointer sigmoid_filter = SigmoidFilter::New();
sigmoid_filter->SetInput(gradient_filter->GetOutput());
sigmoid_filter->SetOutputMinimum(0.0);
sigmoid_filter->SetOutputMaximum(1.0);
sigmoid_filter->SetAlpha(-1.5);
sigmoid_filter->SetBeta(4.0);
sigmoid_filter->Update();
 
FastMarchingFilter::Pointer fast_marching = FastMarchingFilter::New();
NodeContainer::Pointer seeds = NodeContainer::New();
Node node;
const double seedValue = -50.0;
node.SetValue(seedValue);
seeds->Initialize();
 
vector<GeoVec3s>::iterator it = m_clicks_.begin();
int i=0;
for(; it != m_clicks_.end(); it++)
{
    itkIndex index;
    index[0] = (*it)[0];
    index[1] = (*it)[1];
    index[2] = (*it)[2];
    node.SetIndex(index);
    seeds->InsertElement(i++, node);
}
fast_marching->SetTrialPoints(seeds);
fast_marching->SetSpeedConstant(1.0);
fast_marching->SetStoppingValue(100);
//fast_marching->SetInput(sigmoid_filter->GetOutput());
fast_marching->SetOutputSize(sigmoid_filter->GetOutput()->GetBufferedRegion().GetSize());
fast_marching->Update();
 
GeodesicFilter::Pointer geodesic_filter = GeodesicFilter::New();
geodesic_filter->SetInput(fast_marching->GetOutput());
geodesic_filter->SetFeatureImage(sigmoid_filter->GetOutput());
 
geodesic_filter->SetPropagationScaling(0.5);
geodesic_filter->SetCurvatureScaling(5.0);
geodesic_filter->SetAdvectionScaling(1.0);
geodesic_filter->SetMaximumRMSError( 0.02 );
geodesic_filter->Update();
 
BinaryThresholdFilter::Pointer thresholder = BinaryThresholdFilter::New();
thresholder->SetLowerThreshold(-1000);
thresholder->SetUpperThreshold(0);
thresholder->SetOutsideValue(0);
thresholder->SetInsideValue(255);
thresholder->SetInput( geodesic_filter->GetOutput() );
```

I'm using metrics described in [this paper](http://suzukilab.first.iir.titech.ac.jp/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SuzukiKEtAl_CAMeasurementLiverVolumesCTActContSegm_MedPhys2010.pdf) which goal is the same as mine.

I have a few questions:

1. The fast marching filter should output a distance map right? Instead, when I output my volume to a series of png (between values 0 and 4095) I have a binary image (pixels are either 0 or 4095). I think I should get a greyscale volume indicating the time needed for each pixel to be attained from the seeds.
2. Following the procedure described by Suzuki I succeeded to make the algorithm work more or less however I changed the values of the parameters of the geodesic filter. I don't remember the exact values but it wasn't close to those described in the paper. As we are working with the sigmoid input which is normalized between 0 and 1, what is happening?
3. Should I rather use a constant speed function for the fast marching filter or the sigmoid image? When should either method be preferred?
4. I'm using a re-scaler to output my float images (output from the filters). Could this be the reason for the inconsistencies I'm seeing?
5. Any advice on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The fast marching map will have fractional values. You will not be able to see them in a png viewer.

Comment: @nav I thought the rescale intensity filter I'm using would 'normalize' float values in the range I'm giving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found my problem. The Fast Marching filter does output a time crossing map (distance map) but as I specified a stopping value in the algorithm all the pixels that weren't visited had a high value (1.7e+38 as it is half the max value of the type used for the output image which were float in my case 3.4e+38). So it squeezed all my image dynamic when I used the rescale filter and the result was an binary image.
I think better results are achieved with a sigmoid image as input for the fast marching filter.
Thanks @nav for the advice.